# How to get the value of hive variable, in the UDF in Java?

Tags: hive, hiveql

Is it possible to get the value of hive variable which is set in the session like this:

```
> set temp_var=abc;
```

inside the Custom UDF which I am going to call ahead in the same session.
I do not want to pass the variable as a parameter to the UDF. I was looking for a way to do that pro grammatically from within java.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

Say you have below variable set into session via `set` command or within a script.

```
set temp_var=abc;
```

You may use `GenericUDF evaluate()` method to retrieve it:

```
@Override
 public Object evaluate(DeferredObject[] args) throws HiveException {
    String myconf;
    SessionState ss = SessionState.get();
    if (ss != null) {
        HiveConf conf = ss.getConf();
        myconf= conf.get("temp_var");
        System.out.println("sysout.myconf:"+ myconf);
    }
}
```

I would also recommend to override the `configure` method as below to support `MapReduce` program, which might be launched by Hive.

```
  @Override
    public void configure(MapredContext context) {
        super.configure(context);
        JobConf conf = context.getJobConf();
            if (conf != null) {
              String myhiveConf = conf.get("temp_var");
            }
        }
    }
```

The code is tested on hive 1.2